# Can't get OfficialFile.SubmitFile to work

Tags: development, document-library, file-upload, soap

I'm trying to write a literal SOAP call (I'm integrating from a remote non-windows machine) to submit a file which currently resides in the drop-off library of the site. I created a simple file, testing1.txt, upload and set metadata, then call OfficialFile.SubmitFile with the bytestream and some other fields that I got from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920959%28v=office.12%29.aspx). No matter what I do, I always get a NotFound error. The request XML I used is below.

What am I doing wrong??

```
<SubmitFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/recordsrepository/">
<fileToSubmit>aGVsbG8gc2hhcmVwb2ludAo=</fileToSubmit>
<properties>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>ID</Name>
  <Value>107</Value>
  <Type>Counter</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>ContentTypeId</Name>
  <Value>
  0x010100F61F2571157CF04CA067909F68034A00004471681EEFE6FD4EA87735A0F54C2908</Value>
  <Type>ContentTypeId</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>ContentType</Name>
  <Value>Business Requirements</Value>
  <Type>Text</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>Created</Name>
  <Value>03/15/2011 13:27:06</Value>
  <Type>DateTime</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>vti_modifiedby</Name>
  <Value>DOMAIN\userid</Value>
  <Type>String</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>Product</Name>
  <DisplayName>Product_0</DisplayName>
  <Value>Eva|9971C2D8-1760-4515-B408-15162BBC2284</Value>
  <Type>Note</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
<RecordsRepositoryProperty>
  <Name>Country</Name>
  <DisplayName>Country_0</DisplayName>
  <Value>Germany|D14D48E7-9716-4ECD-813F-3E7CA405C92F</Value>
  <Type>Note</Type>
  <Other />
</RecordsRepositoryProperty>
</properties>
<recordRouting>Routing Documents</recordRouting>
<sourceUrl>
/sites/issuem/recordc/DropOffLibrary/testing1.txt</sourceUrl>
<userName>DOMAIN\userid</userName>
</SubmitFile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--development-programming/notfound-error-while-sending-a-document-to-records-center-programmatically-62025.shtml

FTA:

> There is a group called "Records Center Web Service Submitters for recordcenter" whic hbasically specifies the users allowed to submit a record to the record center via the web service. By default, nobody is a member of this group. To add a user go to "Records Center >Peoples and Groups>Groups" and click on the above mentioned group. Add the user to this group, and the above code works....